# Android - Compile with "lunch full-eng"

Tags: android

I am trying to run [PScout](http://pscout.csl.toronto.edu) on a dummy Android application and it requires that the app is compiled using "lunch full-eng". My question is:

1. What is the easiest way to compile an app using this? Do I need to download the entire Android source as outlined [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/android/android_getting_started.html):

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `lunch full-eng` is part of a build of the full tree.

However, I strongly recommend you use the [documentation on the Android site](https://source.android.com/source/requirements.html) itself, rather than a 3rd-party site.